# How to access content inside class library when run in a website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class library name "VirusScanManager" that contains a folder named "Lib". This folder contains a command-line scanner exe and supporting files. All these files have "Build Action" set to "Content" and "Copy to Output Directory" set to "copy always".

Inside the library I get the path to the folder using the following line:

```
string virusCheckFolder 
= Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Lib");
```

I have a Tests class library with a reference to VirusScanManager. When the tests are run the `virusCheckFolder` is set to

`C:\...\Projects\WebSiteMobileAdmin\Tests\bin\Debug\Lib`

and this works because the files are copied there.

I also have a BusinessLogicLayer class library with a reference to VirusScanManager. When I run my website the `virusCheckFolder` is set to

`C:\...\WebSites\WebSiteMobileAdmin\Lib`

this doesn't work because the files are actually copied to

`C:\...\Projects\WebSiteMobileAdmin\BusinessLogic\bin\Debug\Lib`

I then tried reflection as suggested by Beaner:

```
string pathToDLL = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase.Replace("file:///", ""));
string virusCheckFolder = Path.Combine(pathToDLL, "Lib");
```

This gives me

`C:\...\WebSites\WebSiteMobileAdmin\Bin\Lib`

But this folder does not exist.
I have a reference to BusinessLogicLayer in WebsiteMobileAdmin, and a reference to VirusScanManager in BusinessLogicLayer . It appears that when I do a build, the dll is created in both BusinessLogicLayer\bin\debug and WebsiteMobileAdmin\bin, but the lib folder is only copied to BusinessLogicLayer\bin\debug.

So, is there a way to get the path to the internal library that works for both scenarios?

Answer (score 3):

Try using reflection to get your assembly's path, no matter where it is.

```
string strPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I've tried this, but there appear to be 2 copies of the dll, and it's using the version that doesn't have a Lib with it

Comment: I apologize because I am having some trouble understanding what you are doing, but if I am reading correctly your Tests class is in the WebSiteMobileAdmin namespace. Should it be in the WebSiteMobileAdmin\BusinessLogic namespace instead?

Comment: There are 3 class libraries named BusinessLogicLayer, Tests and VirusScanManager, each with their own namespace. The WebSiteMobileAdmin is a website, which has a reference to BusinessLogicLayer. BusinessLogicLayer  has a reference to VirusScanManager. VirusScanManager uses an exe and needs to create a file in a folder. So I have created a sub folder in the VirusScanManager project. I'd like to get the path to the folder internally to VirusScanManager so that I can re-use the class library without having to create a folder in the calling code and pass the path in. Does that help?